# GRANT permission ON database TO user not working on AWS

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.5, amazon-rds, aws

I'm having trouble granting a user permission on AWS.

> ```
> mysql> GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hmrex_db'@'%';
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Grants for hmrex_db@%                                                        |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>         |
> | GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP ON `hmrex_db`.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%' |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

- The user I'm logged in as has `GRANT ..., CREATE, ... ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION`
- `read_only` is `0`.

I can't work out why this isn't working.

I discovered I had made a typo and was setting the permission on a user that doesn't exist, however, this worked. When I fixed the typo, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a combination of a typo, and misreading the output because of tiredness.

> ```
> mysql> GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hmrex_db'@'%';
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Grants for hmrex_db@%                                                        |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>        |
> | GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP ON `hmrex_db`.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%' |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

You'll notice that the set of grants is still `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP`, the same as before. However, what you may not have noticed, and what I didn't notice, is that `USAGE` has changed to `CREATE`.

So, once the typo was fixed, the command was setting the permission correctly, just not where I was expecting to see it! There is a difference between

> `GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%';`

and

> `` GRANT CREATE ON `hmrex_db`.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%'; ``

which you can see in the correct output above in the first row, not in the second row where I was looking.

When I changed the command to `` GRANT CREATE ON `hmrex_db`.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%'; ``, I got the following output:

> ```
> mysql> GRANT CREATE ON `hmrex_db`.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hmrex_db'@'%';
> +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Grants for hmrex_db@%                                                                |
> +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>                 |
> | GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP ON `hmrex_db`.* TO 'hmrex_db'@'%' |
> +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To user/privileges changes be reflected you need to run the following command:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you can try SHOW GRANTS againg.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` is only needed if you are manually `UPDATE`ing the user permission table. When using `GRANT ...;` it's not needed.